# return only first json formatted errors in pre-built authentication RegisterControllers laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I'm using pre-built authentication controllers [suggested larvel 5.4](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#authentication-quickstart).

There is a `validator` function to validate incoming registration request like this :

```
    protected function validator (array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name'     => 'required|string|max:255',
            'family'   => 'required|string|max:255',
            'email'    => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'captcha'  => 'required|captcha'
        ]);
    }
```

Problem is When send an invalid data to `registerController`, laravel return all occurred errors as pre formatted json while I want to return only first error and in this format :

```
{
      "success" : false ,
      "msg" : "error Message comes here"
}
```

How can I do that ?

Comment: ***laravel return all occurred errors*** Yes it does when you use `@error` in view

Comment: I send all requests by Ajax and I want to receive a json formatted error to manage it via jQuery therefore I do not use @error

Answer (score 0):

You may use the bail rule to stop running validation rules on an attribute after the first validation failure as mentioned in laravel documentation:

[image]

In you case you may try with the following:

```
protected function validator (array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name'     => 'bail|required|string|max:255',
            'family'   => 'bail|required|string|max:255',
            'email'    => 'bail|required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'username' => 'bail|required|string|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'bail|required|string|min:6|confirmed',
            'captcha'  => 'bail|required|captcha'
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: How? can you take an example ?

Comment: Can you please check now

Answer (score 0):

simple example

App\Exceptions\Handler

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException) {
        return response()->json(['success'=>false,'msg'=>current($e->errors())]);
    }
    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```